# Использование нейросети

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

обучил нейронку, загружаю её, отдаю файл на predict и в ответ получаю всегда [[1.]], я так понимаю это связанно с одним нейроном на последнем слое, но я не понимаю, ни как она в таком случае обучилась, ни как пофиксить. Нейронка банальный обучающий пример на определение собаки и кошки.

обучение и сохранение:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

# Каталог с данными для обучения
train_dir = 'C:\Projects\python\dogorcat\cats_vs_dogs/train'
# Каталог с данными для проверки
val_dir = 'C:\Projects\python\dogorcat\cats_vs_dogs/val'
# Каталог с данными для тестирования
test_dir = 'C:\Projects\python\dogorcat\cats_vs_dogs/test'
# Размеры изображения
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
# Размерность тензора на основе изображения для входных данных в нейронную сеть
# backend Tensorflow, channels_last
input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
# Количество эпох
epochs = 30
# Размер мини-выборки
batch_size = 16
# Количество изображений для обучения
nb_train_samples = 17500
# Количество изображений для проверки
nb_validation_samples = 3750
# Количество изображений для тестирования
nb_test_samples = 3750

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
prediction = model.predict(input_shape)
print()
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, nb_test_samples // batch_size)

print("Сохраняем сеть")
# Сохраняем сеть для последующего использования
# Генерируем описание модели в формате json
model_json = model.to_json()
json_file = open("cvd_model.json", "w")
# Записываем архитектуру сети в файл
json_file.write(model_json)
json_file.close()
# Записываем данные о весах в файл
model.save_weights("cvd_model.h5")
print("Сохранение сети завершено")
```

загрузка из файла и использование:

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras import utils
import numpy as np

# Загружаем данные об архитектуре сети из файла json
json_file = open("cvd_model.json", "r")
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
# Создаем модель на основе загруженных данных
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# Загружаем веса в модель
loaded_model.load_weights("cvd_model.h5")

loaded_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print()
img_path = input('input path to image\n')
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(150, 150), grayscale=False)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

img_arr = image.img_to_array(img)
img_arr /= 255
img_arr = np.expand_dims(img_arr, axis=0)
prediction = loaded_model.predict(img_arr)
prediction = utils.to_categorical(prediction)
print(prediction)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно для данной задачи необходимо использовать деление на три разных категории с помощью `classes=['cats', 'dogs', 'other']` , т.е. генераторы должны иметь вид

```
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical', classes=['cats', 'dogs', 'other'])

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical', classes=['cats', 'dogs', 'other'])

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical', classes=['cats', 'dogs', 'other'])

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

также активатором последнего слоя должен быть `softmax`